# Best way to convert a writeable bitmap to byte[] array after compression?

Tags: c#, silverlight, bitmap, compression

I'm using a webcam to capture an image in silverlight. now i need to convert it into a byte[] array. Right now I use something like this:

```
WriteableBitmap img = e.Result;
int[] p = img.Pixels;
int len = p.Length * 4;
byte[] result = new byte[len]; // ARGB
Buffer.BlockCopy(p, 0, result, 0, len);
```

However, the size of the resultant arrray is about 2MB which is rather large. What are my options for achieving better compression? (right now I'm thinking of using some opensource compression code and reducing the size of the cam).

Comment: What's large about 2MB when your RAM has 4GB? :)

Comment: Need to pass it through a WCF service to save it in a database so reducing size would provide significant performance improvement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [BitmapEncoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapencoder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to encode your bitmap as jpeg or png.

The docu has some example how to use it. Don't know if this is available in silverlight though.

Anyways it might be a good idea to use something like https://imagetools.codeplex.com/ because this library should work fine with silverlight and you don't have to struggle with issues getting your own implementation running...